# What is the nth term for this sequence?

Tags: css, css-selectors, logic, sequence

```html
<div class="row form-row ">
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
</div>
```

I want to colour the background of a div determined on its nth term. I am using bootstrap columns to arrange these divs. On a small screens and up I am setting two columns to take a row.

My sequence doesn't converge. It goes as follows:
bootstrap row = (1st row) white, black 
                (2nd row) black, white
                (3rd row) white, black

What nth term can I set in :nth-child() to colour the columns like this?

I have tried 4n+3 and 4n+1 but have had no success.

Comment: please share the relevant markup and specify the desired colour for every div

Comment: as you are alternating rows, then you would use `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)`

Comment: @fcalderan I have inserted my markup, this is using bootstrap 4

Comment: @Pete that does not work because the second row would be white black, when I want black, white

Comment: You'd need to adjust the nth-term in your media queries. There is no single solution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row .squareBG:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white
}
.row .squareBG:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="row form-row ">
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
    <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort but this will not work because the row is a bootstrap row and the columns are repeating in one row.

Comment: got it. since you need each column in the row to have an alternate color, I have updated the code. Check if this works for you.

Comment: @ynwebdev check the updated solution I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You spotted that the pattern repeats every 4 elements. You then just need to go to the 4th element (4n) and then add however many it takes to move to the next black background div. In this case you need to add two to get to the first one and three to get to the second one.

So that means you can use `4n+2` and `4n+3`:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.squareBG {
  width: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
}

.squareBG:nth-child(4n+2),
.squareBG:nth-child(4n+3) {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row form-row ">
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div> <!-- 4n -->
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div> <!-- +2 -->
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div> <!-- +3 -->
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">Black BG</div>
  <div class="squareBG col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border">White BG</div>
</div>
```